# How to use getview() with a SimpleAdapter from AsyncTask?

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

I'm generating a ListView using a SimpleAdapter like this:

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(TodayActivity.this, detailslist,
    R.layout.singlerow, new String[] {"name","cname","cid","pid"},
    new int[] { R.id.textView2,R.id.textView3,R.id.clid,R.id.projectid}){

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if(details.containsValue("12")){
            //here if that value exits in hashmap
            //I need to change a colour for that item position.         
        }  
        return v;
    }
};
```

MyHashmap

```
HashMap<String, String> details = new HashMap<String, String>();

// adding each child node to HashMap key => value
details.put("name", "Project Name: "+Name);
details.put("cname", client_name);
details.put("cid", client_id);
details.put("pid", project_id);
details.put("flag", "False");
```

Here I need to put a condition for particular value is exits in my hashmap or not, if that value exits I need to change a colour for that item position. I have tried it's not working. How can I do that? Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56100/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-make-it-simple).

Answer (score 0):

Try This code in your getView

```
v.setBackgroundColor(youCondition? 0x9934B5E4: Color.TRANSPARENT);   

    return v;
```

Comment: I have tried your answer  `v.setBackgroundColor(details.containsValue("12")? 0x9934B5E4: Color.TRANSPARENT);` all items are TRANSPARENT